# How do I send mass text on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4s and want to send a mass text. How do I send a mass text to 30 people without sending to everyone else in my Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages to a Contact Group - start to type the Group's name, then select when you see it in the list...

[image]

Comment: or, just like in mail, keep typing names and adding them to the message. Tho not sure if Messages supports that many recipients, I guess you will find out.